# Sorting in a hashMap

Tags: java, sorting, methods, arraylist, hashmap

I'm having some trouble sorting out this code, which is in a hashmap - I also need some help sorting out a similar code set for a double (price). Thank You.

```
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
public class Inventory {

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    ArrayList<Sellable> groceries;
    HashMap<String, Integer> stock;

    public Inventory() {
        groceries = new ArrayList<Sellable>();
        stock = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
//HARDCODING...:
        Sellable n1 = new Produce("Corn", 3, 5.00);
        Sellable n2 = new Snack("Natural Popcorn Seeds", 2.50);
        Sellable n3 = new Produce("Potatoes", 3, 5.00);
        Sellable n4 = new Snack("Organic Potato Chips", 2.50);
        Sellable n5 = new Produce("Apples", 5, 1.75);
        Sellable n6 = new Snack("Apple Juice - 128 oz.", 3.50);
        Sellable n7 = new Produce("Oranges", 5, 1.75);
        Sellable n8 = new Snack("Orange Juice - 128 oz.", 3.50);
//ADD TO HASHMAP
        groceries.add(n1);
        groceries.add(n2);
        groceries.add(n3);
        groceries.add(n4);
        groceries.add(n5);
        groceries.add(n6);
        groceries.add(n7);
        groceries.add(n8);
//PUT UP FOR PRINTING
        stock.put(n1.getName(), 50);
        stock.put(n2.getName(), 100);
        stock.put(n3.getName(), 50);
        stock.put(n4.getName(), 100);
        stock.put(n5.getName(), 50);
        stock.put(n6.getName(), 100);
        stock.put(n7.getName(), 50);
        stock.put(n8.getName(), 100);
    }

//Sorting Method 1
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public void sortByName() {
        groceries = new ArrayList<Sellable>();
        stock = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
        {
            if (stock != null) {
                List<Sellable> groceries = new ArrayList<Sellable>();
                stock.addAll(((Entry<String, Integer>) stock).getValue(), groceries);
                Collections.sort(groceries, new Comparator<Sellable>() {
                    public int compare(Sellable product1, Sellable product2) {
                        try {
                            Sellable choice1 = (Sellable) product1;
                            Sellable choice2 = (Sellable) product2;
                            //LESS THAN
                            if (choice1.getName().compareTo(choice2.getName()) < 0) {
                                return -1;
                            } //GREATER THAN
                            else if (choice1.getName().compareTo(choice2.getName()) > 0) {
                                return 1;
                            } //EQUALS
                            else {
                                return 0;
                            }
                        } catch (ClassCastException FAIL) {
                            return -2;
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you *please* format your code.  When I see `});}}` my brain hurts (thank you @mKorbel for that edit).  Specifically, what problem are you having with the code?

Comment: Please implement `Comparable` in your class: `class Sellable implements Comparable<Sellable>{ @Override public int compareTo(Sellable other){ } }`

Comment: **sorting out** is not the same as **sorting**

Comment: I'm trying to figure out how to sort what all of the elements hardcoded into my inventory object. Sorry if your brain hurts - mine does too from trying to figure it out...

Comment: @Mr. Polywhirl --> Sellable is an interface, not a class, unfortunately...

Comment: You can sort lists, not Hashmaps. You can get lists of keys or list of values from your Map, and sort that.

Comment: So how would I go about sorting that ArrayList (and making sure the HasMap doesn't conflict with anything) in that part of code is my real question, if that's the case...

Comment: @user2891351: you typically should not use floating-point numbers unless you're doing scientific computation. Use *cents* as the base unit and represent your grocery store prices using integers and you'll save yourself lots of headaches.

Comment: @user2891351 You can make it an abstract class.

Comment: @user2891351 In your "sortByName" method you are re-initialing the member variables which will create new object for the same class variables. Then you are making a local variable "List<Sellable> groceries = new ArrayList<Sellable>();" which will again a n empty list. So there wont be any object for comparison.

Answer (score 0):

Please remove the lines of code,

`groceries = new ArrayList<Sellable>();`

`stock = new HashMap<String, Integer>();`

from your mehod `sortByName().`

This lines reset the `groceries` and `stock` to empty.

Comment: I did it and fixed it, accordingly. It's still not sorting properly, but I did manage to get rid of most of the errors plaguing it. Thank you, otherwise...

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but neither your code or your Question makes a lot of sense to me.

- Your `sortByName` is clobbering both `groceries` and `stock`.
- Then it is apparently *attempting* to copy from the (now) empty HashMap to the ArrayList.  But it is nonsensical because

  - you are attempting to use a non-existent method (`HashMap.addAll`),
  - you are casting a `HashMap` to an `Entry`,
  - and so on.
- The `Comparator` looks plausible for sorting "by name", but your code that returns -2 in the event of a ClassCastException is wrong.  You should just let the exception propagate ... if it arises.  You don't actually do a type-cast in the Comparator.  The arguments have the correct type.  (Casting a `Sellable` to a `Sellable`?   Why ???)

Comment: I admit - I wasn't thinking things out completely. I overanalyzed a simple solution, but that isn't the best way for me to put it, either.

Answer (score 0):

Thought of adding a new answer instead of editing my previous answer.

Please note that you should not (re)initialize the member variables in methods unless it is really required. Also I have used String.compareTo() to compare names.

Please find below the modified sort method:

```
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public void sortByName() {
//        groceries = new ArrayList<Sellable>();
//        stock = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

            if (stock != null) {
                //List<Sellable> groceries = new ArrayList<Sellable>();
                //stock.addAll(((Entry<String, Integer>) stock).getValue(), groceries);
                Collections.sort(groceries, new Comparator<Sellable>() {
                    public int compare(Sellable product1, Sellable product2) {
                        try {
                            return product1.getName().compareTo(product2.getName());

                        } catch (Exception FAIL) {
                            return -2;
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        }

}
```